# What was the role of Jackie Costigan?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-departed

Billy Costigan's uncle Jackie is mentioned in [*The Departed*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/) with Queenan and Dignam, then again during Sullivan's briefing scene. How was he important to Frank Costello's crew?

Answer (score 1):

It's never mentioned what his exact role was. All we know is that he was working for Costello as a probably not too important but loyal mobster.

We learn that he probably was no stranger to violence when Costello approaches Billy:

> **Costello** [Talking about Billies father] No. He kept his own counsel. He never wanted money. You can't do anything with a man like that. You're Uncle Jackie - he also would kill my entire fucking family if he saw me here with you. And I think about this.

So Costello is implying that Jackie was a different man than his brother William Costigan. He spoke his mind and could be motivated with money.

A later conversation makes it clear that Jackie had earned his trust in the crew:

> **Frank Costello:** [talking about Costigan] Do you trust him?
>   **Mr. French:** Well these days, who's reliable?
>   **Frank Costello:** His uncle Jackie was. Yeah, you can't trust a guy acts like he's got nothing to lose.

He got killed when Billy was still young:

> **Ellerby:** By organized crime in the city, you know who we mean - that's Jackie Costigan, that's an old picture. Jackie met his demise. Last known photograph.

(all quotes taken from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/quotes))

That is pretty much all I could find regarding Jackie. He did not play a big role in the movie, the main purpose of the character was to give Billy Costigan a family connection to the mob. He is the reason Costello approached and recruited him, because he knew and trusted Jackie and saw that potential in Jackie's nephew as well.